# Replay Ruby on Rails logs including parameters and session information?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, parameters, jmeter

[JMeter's Access Log Sampler](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#Access%5FLog%5FSampler) requires common log format logs to replay http requests. I want to use it to replay actions in a Rails application from the log, including params passing. Is there any way to do this with JMeter or any other tool?  I suppose I could parse the logs into `curl` requests, but can this way maintain session information (keeping track of which user performed which action)?

**Edit** I should say what this is for. It can be useful for either performance testing or data recovery. In our case we need to verify some data in the database by using our logs because the db may have data integrity issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am looking at [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) to get this kind of functionality in the future. For the app in question, we had to do some heavy-duty log parsing to get the results we needed. It included separating the actions out by IP address (thus similating sessions, although some IP addresses contained multiple user sessions) and parsing the actions and params in the logs. It was not 100% effective at reproducing the exact state of the database, but it was pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Raw Request for JMeter may help with this